# concat strings from nested objects arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i need to concat all the 'externalId'(inside prod obj) + "id" (inside sup array) + "name" (inside product obj). What would be the best way to do that? I've tried with map and reduce but I wasn't successful. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const jsonResultKeys = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']


const items = [];


jsonResultKeys.forEach(k => {
            const item = Jsonresult.items[k];
            items.push({
                description: item.product.name + ':' + item.product.sup[0] + ':'+ item.product.sup[0].prod.externalId ,
            })
        });
```

the output expected for this example:

```
[ 
{ description: '4444:2:product1'},
{ description: '3333:2:product2'},
{ description: '2222:1:product3'}
]
```

> the json object:

```
const Jsonresult = {
        items: {
          'AAA': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: **4444**
                    },
                    id: **2**
                }],
                name: "**product 1**"
            },
            total: 9.84,
            quantity: 1,
            price: 15,
            updatedAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00'
          },
          'BBB': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: **3333**
                    },
                    id: **2**
                }],
                name: "**product 2**"
            },
            total: 9.84,
            quantity: 1,
            price: 15,
            updatedAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00'
          },
          'CCC': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: **2222**
                    },
                    id: **1**
                    
                }],
                name: "**product 3**"
            },

          }
        },
    }
```

Comment: You're missing `.id` at the end of `item.product.sup[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array#map()` method is the most logical method to use - see @MichaelMano's solution - but if you have to use `.push()` to populate `items` `(const)` then stick with `.forEach()` as follows:

```
 Object.values( Jsonresult.items ).forEach(item => {
    items.push( {description: `${item.product.sup[0].prod.externalId}:${item.product.sup[0].id}:${item.product.name}`} );
 });
```

**DEMO**

```js
const items = [];

const Jsonresult = {
        items: {
          'AAA': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: 4444
                    },
                    id: 2
                }],
                name: "product 1"
            },
            total: 9.84,
            quantity: 1,
            price: 15,
            updatedAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00'
          },
          'BBB': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: 3333
                    },
                    id: 2
                }],
                name: "product 2"
            },
            total: 9.84,
            quantity: 1,
            price: 15,
            updatedAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00'
          },
          'CCC': {
            createdAt: '2021-02-11T17:25:22.960-03:00',
            product: {
                sup: [{
                    prod: {
                        externalId: 2222
                    },
                    id: 1
                    
                }],
                name: "product 3"
            },

          }
        },
    };
    
 Object.values( Jsonresult.items ).forEach(item => {
      items.push( {description: `${item.product.sup[0].prod.externalId}:${item.product.sup[0].id}:${item.product.name}`} );
 });
 
    
    console.log( items );
```

Comment: my Jsonresult obj is not ordered, so the sup[0] is not working.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean, or post the correct JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, Map over the results and return an object, this will create an array of objects.

You wont even need the keys.

```
const map = Object.values(Jsonresult.items).map((item) => {
    return {
        description: `${item.product.sup[0].prod.externalId}:${item.product.sup[0].id}:${item.product.name}`,
    };
});
```

```
[
  { description: '4444:2:product 1' },
  { description: '3333:2:product 2' },
  { description: '2222:1:product 3' }
]
```

Comment: tks @Michael . But I need to push the return into array "items" variable. how can I do that?